# How to align anchor to center irrespective of previous element length

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I have few panels which has panel tool, text and an anchor with `fa`. Now I want to keep the anchor centered, and not able to do that.

If I keep the anchor in a new div, the new div being is pushed down.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-10">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="panel-group">
            <!--Panel 1 -->
            <div class="panel">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="panel-tools">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#1" aria-expanded="false">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <span><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i>Some Archive Management</span>
                        <a class="btn btn-sm btn-info text-center">
                            <i class="fa fa-bar-chart text-primary"></i> Show Graph
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-10">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="panel-group">
            <!--Panel 3 -->
            <div class="panel">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="panel-tools">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#3" aria-expanded="false">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <span><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i>Other Management</span>
                        <a class="btn btn-sm btn-info text-center">
                            <i class="fa fa-bar-chart text-primary"></i> Show Graph
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-10">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="panel-group">
            <!--Panel 24 -->
            <div class="panel">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="panel-tools">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#24" aria-expanded="false">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <span><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i> Today's Summary</span>
                        <a class="btn btn-sm btn-info text-center">
                            <i class="fa fa-bar-chart text-primary"></i> Show Graph
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xos71g5v/

**Edit, expected output**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.panel-heading div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.panel div span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 180px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-10">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="panel-group">
            <div class="panel">
                    <div class="panel-heading">                       
                        <div class="panel-tools">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#1" aria-expanded="false">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <span><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i>Some Archive Management</span>
                            <a class="btn btn-sm btn-info text-center">
                                <i class="fa fa-bar-chart text-primary"></i>
                                Show Graph
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-10">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="panel-group">
            <div class="panel">
                    <div class="panel-heading">                       
                        <div class="panel-tools">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#3" aria-expanded="false">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <span><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i>Other Management</span>
                            <a class="btn btn-sm btn-info text-center">
                                <i class="fa fa-bar-chart text-primary"></i>
                                Show Graph
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-10">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="panel-group">
            <div class="panel">
                    <div class="panel-heading">                       
                        <div class="panel-tools">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#24" aria-expanded="false">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <span><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i> Today's Summary</span>
                            <a class="btn btn-sm btn-info text-center">
                                <i class="fa fa-bar-chart text-primary"></i>
                                Show Graph
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The button is still being aligned as per content length

Comment: Can you provide any screen shot as you want output...?

Comment: The button is still aligning as per span length .

Answer (score 1):

Use two divisions.
Give 50% width to the first div and also give float: left property.

```css
   
.fifty{
  width:50%;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-10">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="panel-group">

                                <!--Panel 3 -->

                
            <div class="panel">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                       
                        <div class="panel-tools">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#3" aria-expanded="false">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class='fifty'>
                            <span><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i>Other Management</span>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                            <a class="btn btn-sm btn-info text-center">
                                <i class="fa fa-bar-chart text-primary"></i>
                                Show Graph
                            </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                       
                        
                       
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-10">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="panel-group">

                                <!--Panel 24 -->

                
            <div class="panel">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                       
                        <div class="panel-tools">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#24" aria-expanded="false">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class='fifty'>
                            <span><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i> Today's Summary</span>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                            <a class="btn btn-sm btn-info text-center">
                                <i class="fa fa-bar-chart text-primary"></i>
                                Show Graph
                            </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've just added new class 'fifty' for the first division.

Answer (score -1):

```css
/**You can try this css code this might helpful.**/
.panel .panel-heading {
  float: left;
}
.panel .panel-tools {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-10">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="panel-group">
            <!--Panel 1 -->
            <div class="panel">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="panel-tools">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#1" aria-expanded="false">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <span><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i>Some Archive Management</span>
                        <a class="btn btn-sm btn-info text-center">
                            <i class="fa fa-bar-chart text-primary"></i> Show Graph
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-10">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="panel-group">
            <!--Panel 3 -->
            <div class="panel">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="panel-tools">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#3" aria-expanded="false">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <span><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i>Other Management</span>
                        <a class="btn btn-sm btn-info text-center">
                            <i class="fa fa-bar-chart text-primary"></i> Show Graph
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-10">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="panel-group">
            <!--Panel 24 -->
            <div class="panel">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="panel-tools">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#24" aria-expanded="false">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <span><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i> Today's Summary</span>
                        <a class="btn btn-sm btn-info text-center">
                            <i class="fa fa-bar-chart text-primary"></i> Show Graph
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```